# Counter on matlab using for loop

Tags: matlab, counter

I have provided the function file for a similar question for the input vector of size 3. you can try running it.

```
function neha(limit) 

c = zeros(1,3);

for i = 0:limit(3)-1 % same as running it from 1:limit(3)

    c(3)=i;

    for j = 0:limit(2)-1

        c(2)=j;

        for k=0:limit(1)-1

            c(1)=k;

            for x=3:-1:1

                fprintf('%d ',c(x))
            end

            fprintf('\n');

        end
    end
end

return
```

now my question is : Create a "counter" from 0:limit-1. The length of counter is not determined in the program and it should be determined when it is being run and the inputs can differ from each other. this means that the input vector size is not given and it has to work for any input be it 1,2 or 50. now how do i make a function file for this question? help pls

Comment: Stop asking the same question multiple times. If want to add something extra edit your old questions. But this question has been comprehensively answered

Comment: you clearly dont understand my question, but thanks for trying Dan.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question...try this recursive function

```
function neha(limit,pointer)

if nargin == 1 %first call
    pointer = 1;
end 

for i = 1:limit(pointer)
    limit_ = limit;
    limit_(pointer) = i;    
    if pointer == length(limit)
        fprintf('%d ',limit_-1); %print result
        fprintf('\n');
    else
        neha(limit_,pointer+1); %run recursively
    end
end 
end
```

Call neha(limit), you don't have to specify the argument "pointer". Hope that helps.